# LDAP auth for MongoDB with Pam

Tags: mongodb, ldap, openldap

I am working to get MongoDB (using the Percona distro) to authenticate using Pam.  I can see lots of info about using SASL, but the company standard is pam and I'm not able to change that.  I see a project from 2011 in GitHub (pam_mongodb) that says it works, but given the age I'm hoping for a better solution.  I have RHEL 7.5, Mongo 3.6.5, and and have cyrus-sasl 2.1.26 installed, but not configured.

Any suggestions?  I am completely new to LDAP and trying to fumble my way through, so pointers to web pages are also helpful.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm surprised how little there is on the internet about this

Comment: See my reply on how to configure PAM Auth against MongoDB Enterprise Edition : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600693/configuring-mongodb-to-authenticate-users-password-via-linux-pam/55343503#55343503

Comment: I found that using Percona Server for MongoDB has LDAP using SASL available.  Not as complete as I'd like, though; groups don't seem to work well in that event.  PSMDB is an enhanced version of the community MongoDB, and is a no-cost option.