# Configuring MongoDB to authenticate user's password via Linux PAM

Tags: mongodb, pam

I'm looking for a way to configure MongoDB to use Linux PAM to manage user passwords. This way when a user changes their password, it doesn't have to be manually updated in Mongodb.

Searching for help for this online only returns one result which is a blog [article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/securing-mongodb-part-2-database-access-control) that mentions this is possible but doesn't describe how this is done.

[image]

The official documentation skips over setting up PAM and talks about LDAP.

#### How can I configure Mongodb to authenticate db users via Linux PAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MongoDB authentication using PAM Linux seems to be configurable only in **MongoDB Enterprise Edition**.

This is because PAM Authentication requires PLAIN Authentication Mechanism, available only in MongoDB Enterprise Edition as mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#authentication-parameters):

> PLAIN (LDAP SASL)   External authentication using LDAP. You can also use PLAIN for authenticating in-database users. PLAIN transmits passwords in plain text. *This mechanism is available only in MongoDB Enterprise.*

BTW, in MongoDB Enterprise Edition, you can enable PAM Authentication using the following (tested on **Debian Stretch**):

### Install saslauthd

`apt-get install sasl2-bin`

`vi /etc/default/saslauthd`

```
START=yes
```

`/etc/init.d/saslauthd restart`

At this step you may test your sasl configuration with ("myuser" is your unix user):

`testsaslauthd -u <myuser> -p <SecretPassword>`

This should output a success message:

```
0: OK "Success."
```

### Create a MongoDB user "myuser"

Replace "myuser" with the user with whom you want to authenticate.

`mongo admin`

```
db.getSiblingDB("$external").createUser(
    {
      user : "myuser",
      roles: [ { role: "read", db: "mydb" } ]
    }
)
```

### Configure MongoDB to enable PLAIN Authentication Mechanism

`vi /etc/mongod.conf`

```
security:
  authorization: enabled

setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: PLAIN,MONGODB-X509,SCRAM-SHA-1,SCRAM-SHA-256
```

You should add the (Linux) mongodb user to the sasl group (this makes sure that MongoDB has the permission to access saslauthd)

`adduser mongodb sasl`

Restart mongod

`systemctl restart mongod.service`

### Connect to MongoDB

Now, on MongoDB Enterprise, you should be able to authenticate using your linux username/pwd:

`mongo --authenticationMechanism=PLAIN --authenticationDatabase='$external' -u myuser mydb`

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("********-****-****-****-************") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.7
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

On MongoDB Community Edition, it sadly fails with an "Unsupported mechanism" error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-03-25T18:26:51.307+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: Unsupported mechanism 'PLAIN' on authentication database '$external' :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):3:6
exception: connect failed
```